# Descargar una imagen con el nombre del archivo como parametro en .Net Core

Tags: imagen, netcore, descargar

estoy desarrollando un método el cual me devuelva una imagen, necesito enviarle como parámetro el nombre de la imagen y que me retorne la descarga del archivo, sin embargo tengo el siguiente error:

> {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One
> or more validation errors
> occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-696bc0932ed24d22e1c2fbe325174409-dfd2cb2e282e57f7-00","errors":{"FileName":["The
> FileName field is required."]}}

Adjunto mi código, agradezco su ayuda ya que no se que es lo que me falta.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileResult DescargarArchivo2(string FileName)
    {

        string contentType = "image/jpeg";          
        String ruta = "D:\\CarpètaArchivosPDF\\"+ FileName;
        byte[] bites = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ruta);
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition",
            $"attachment; filename=\"{FileName}\"");
        return File(bites, contentType);//resultado
    }
```

Comment: el error dice que el campo "FileName" es requerido. estás seguro que lo estás agregando?

Comment: Hola, lo que ocurre es que el error sale al ejecutar el proyecto, supongo que en el código me falta agregar el FileName en alguna otra parte pero no sé cual es.